# Allowed to point people to other questions, when they are similar and they could be able to help?

Tags: discussion, comments, similar-questions

I just opened a question on SO. ([How to target my portable class library in a Nuget-Package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468004/how-to-target-my-portable-class-library-in-a-nuget-package))

The question is very similar to the one I found also on SO, but doesn't answer my question. ([Not sure how to make a NuGet package for this PCL library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953323/not-sure-how-to-make-a-nuget-package-for-this-pcl-library/))

I am pretty sure, the person that answered the question is able to help me also on my question. That's why I wanted to point him to my question and commented his answer.

Of course I will delete the comment later on, because it has nothing to do with the question, but just to let him know I commented the answer.

Is that a legit action? Or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 5):

From my experiences with similar comments, you're not going to get in trouble. The worst that will happen is that your comment will be flagged and maybe deleted by a mod. I have flagged similar comments in the past, usually as obsolete (now part of the "no longer needed" flag reason) since they sometimes hang around for years.

On the other hand, you could do better. Why not include a link to the question/answer **in your question**? There should be more than one person capable of solving the issue, and the link will provide context and reduce the likelihood that your question is closed as a duplicate of that other question.

I think that this message (a canned comment from the low quality answer queue) is relevant:

> If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.